# 220v/5v relay stucking problem

Tags: relay

I am a beginner.

I am having a problem with a 220V/5V relay. It works when I try it out of the circuit, but when I connect it to a 220V source and try to switch it, it stays stuck and doesn't move.

When I remove it from the circuit and try to run it, it doesn't work until I hit it strongly to the table . I don't know what the problem is. I replaced it many times and the same happens every time.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_welding

Comment: @user43037 . Are you using an ark snubber at its output ? . What type of load are you driving with your relay?.

Comment: What is your source to command it? 
What is the connected load to the 220V part?

Comment: sorry its 220v not 120v the load is 3 florescent lambs

Comment: and the source of command  is a micro-controller connected with a transistor

Comment: The relay contacts are welding. You need to use a better relay- rated for either an inductive load or a heavy surge depending on what is causing the welding.

Comment: Several commenters have suggested that the contacts may be welding shut. The fact that the relay sticks until you strike it on the table makes this seem quite likely. I'd try to solve this issue first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not clear what is your 5V source to command the relay and how much current it can source. If it's a 4.5V battery, it may not work. The amount of required current is either written on the relay itself of you will find it on it's datasheet.

I think that your 5V source is not able to give enough current to drive your relay this is why it is not switching when there is some load connected to it.

If the relay stay closed what you remove the command, then it's something else:

- Too much current through it
- Over voltage

Comment: sorry its 220/5v relay not 120 and in the circuit i am connecting a 9v battery with a regulator which finally gives 5v
actually the relay works very good but when i connect it in the circuit, it doesn't switch again even when i picked it out the circuit , should i increase the voltage of the battery ? or the relay will break down?

Comment: If you have something to measure the voltage: Measure it across the relay when you are driving it. It should remains more of less 5V. if it falls, you battery does not have enough "juice" to power this relay. Increasing the voltage may help but this is bad practice. You should use your relay within its specifications and provide a driver that is able to supply enough current for it but still at 5V.